# Alter a table column to 4000Byte - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, alter

I need to give a script to DBA to alter the length of a column to 4000 Byte and not 4000 Char.

Since I cannot execute the script on DB due to inadequate permission and conflicting answers on Web, I am not sure of the script.

Please let me know if this one is correct:

```
ALTER TABLE AAA.BBB_CCC MODIFY(VALUE VARCHAR2(4000));
```

I think :

```
ALTER TABLE AAA.BBB_CCC MODIFY(VALUE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR));
```

would create column size of 4000 Char

Comment: have mentioned that the script will be given to DBA. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE AAA.BBB_CCC MODIFY DDD varchar2(4000 BYTE);
```

Comment: Thanks .Does that mean if I have :  ALTER TABLE AAA.BBB_CCC MODIFY DDD varchar2(4000); it is going to change to 4000char.

Comment: I'd have to double check the docs, but I believe it defaults to CHAR when unspecified.

Comment: Works well without '(' on MySQL where  I have access. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to modify column.

```
Create table abc(
id varchar2(400)
);

============
Table created.

alter table abc modify id varchar2(4000 byte);
============
Table altered.
```

Comment: The OP specifically stated they don't want CHAR.